# As a level 35 sith juggernaut how do I make credits fast

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

As of the most recent updates how do I make credits fast? I am on taris and am level 35. I have not defeated any world bosses but am thinking of doing so. I dont have very many items but I have a speeder.

Are there any places that are good for farming  that have levels lower than mine?

And are there ways to make credits off the gtn?

Comment: Other than possibly identifying in-demand low-level crafting materials on your server and farming them,  the fastest way is going to be getting to level 65 and following the advice for endgame players.

Comment: @Frank no I am talking about the current version as the game has been updated since then. also I have a level cap on mine.

Comment: Yeah; I actually bountied the question because I had the same thought.  There's an updated answer from only a couple months ago.

Comment: well I just wanted to know how to do it at my level

Comment: And the original question was for level 20.  That seems applicable enough.

Comment: always a nice way to get some cash is to do the PvP battles and actually kill stuff ( way to much money in my opinion)